# Unable to install bbpress themes

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I am having an issue with a wordpress and a bbpress plugin. I need to install a bbpress theme, but I can't seem to have them show up in admin, although I put it in the right directory. I have also tried with other themes, same result.

Comment: Can you specify what directory you are putting the themes in?

Comment: in bbp-themes. I have managed to make the template show up in admin, but when I activate it, the website crashes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hacky, but I was able to theme `bbpress` by building a child theme. By making a child theme instead of altering the plugin theme directly, you will make sure that your style changes won’t be overwritten if and when you update the plugin.

1. Start by copying the `bbpress` theme out of the plugin folder (I started working off the `bbp-twentyten` theme), and pasting it into the **Wordpress** themes folder.  Rename it with whatever you want your new `bbpress` theme to be called.   Go into *themes **>** your child theme's name **>** style.css*  and add this in the header:

   `@import url('../ the name of your parent theme /style.css');`

   - Theme Name: Name of your Child theme
   - Description: Description of child theme.
   - Author: Your name
   - Template: The name of your parent theme
2. Go in to the *appearance **>** theme* area of your **Wordpress** dashboard and see if your new theme appears. If it does, install it.

   Your site should look exactly like it did before. What happens is that @import url allows the theme to pull all the styles from the parent theme, which you can then override without messing up the original.
3. Now edit the `style.css` file in *themes **>** your-child-theme*.  Just be aware that if you make a change that doesn’t seem to load, you may need to add an !important to the style.